# Query Array Struct column in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to query Array Struct datatype column using Spark SQL

Column Name: `Metrics`

Column DataType: `array<struct<metrics_name:string, metrics_value:double>>`

Sample Value: `WrappedArray([cpu,1.0000], [memory,9.8828125])`

and I don't want to hardcord the position to get the data e.g.

for cpu data - `metrics[0].metrics_value`
for memory data - `metrics[1].metrics_value`

Answer (score 0):

```
spark.sql("""select distinct metrics
,case when array_contains(metrics.metrics_name, 'cpu') == true then metrics[array_position(metrics.metrics_name, 'cpu')-1].metrics_value  end as cpu
,case when array_contains(metrics.metrics_name, 'memory') == true then metrics[array_position(metrics.metrics_name, 'memory')-1].metrics_value  end as memory
FROM   
    table_name limit 10""").show(false)
```

output:
[image]